# crop image and display cropped image in axes

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, crop, matlab-guide

i have an image and i want to crop it i applied this code but its only cropping the image but not showing the cropped image on the axes :

```
imrect(Iedge2)
hPlot = plot(xBox, yBox);
pause(2)
delete(hPlot)
cla('reset')
imshow(I, []);  % No need to specify 'Parent' now.
title('Cropped Image', 'FontSize', 12);
```

i want to show the message on the top of the axes area that "crop the image" when the crop process occurs and after selection of the area the cropped area will be shown to the `axes2 .some body please tell me is there is any function or method to do so?

thanks and regards`

Comment: looks like there is code missing. Care to add it so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: sir i have written this code as i am learner of  matlab i can't get what is missing there "edge2 is an image" and i want to crop the image automatically where there are some characters or line. i want to remove the extra area of the image. or if the user done this manually than there should be a message on top of axes that please crop image when the crop marker appears on the axes image.after this the cropped image will be displayed in axes and title will be as "cropped image "

Comment: @Benoit_11  this is the code in this code what i want is to show an title on the top of axes when the user have to select the area for crop like "please crop the area youn want"                                                                          a=imcrop(Iedge2);
title ('please crop image', 'FontSize', 15)
pause(3)
axes(handles.axes2)
imshow(a, []);  % No need to specify 'Parent' now.
title('Cropped Image', 'FontSize', 15);

Comment: a=imcrop(Iedge2);
pause(3)
axes(handles.axes2)
imshow(a, []);  % No need to specify 'Parent' now.
title('Cropped Image', 'FontSize', 15);
sir this code is working as i want but how can i add title to the axes when the crop cursor on the image something like this :

a=imcrop(Iedge2, title 'please Crop the Image', 'FontSize', 15);

Comment: with regards please help me out to perform such operation